# How to open a folder or a file with the help of file path in OS x programatically?

Tags: ios, macos, nsfilemanager, nsdocument, nsdocumentcontroller

I have selected a file using NSOpenPanel and save its url path, but at any time in my os x Application i want to open this file in the default mac application.Suppose if I select an file and click on the open button in my app the file should open in default preview.
How could i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 2):

For IOS

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

For OSX

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
```